# General convention for python libraries that also have an interface module?

Tags: python, distribution, conventions, distutils

Right now I've got a project that has the following layout:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
  foo.py
```

In this case, `foo.py` is actually the main api file, so developers are meant to do "from foo import foo", but I also wanted to make it so that end users could just run `~$ foo` and get an interface.

which, when I do a distutils install, creates `/usr/bin/__main__.py` because (a) I don't know how to use distutils, [less important] and (b) I am not sure about what is generally considered to be the Right Thing.

As far as I can tell I have three options:

1. Make distutils smarter, so that `setup.py install` creates the
   symlink `/usr/bin/foo -> $PYTHONLIB/foo/__main__.py`. This is my
   immediate intuition, and I could probably figure out how to do it,
   although the things that I'm thinking of doing all feel like hacks
   and I haven't found anybody talking about this.
2. Rename `__main__.py` to just `foo` before distribution, and modify the call to
   distutils' setup to be `setup(scripts=['foo'], ...)`. This is pretty similar to (1), except for when it happens, I think.
3. Just don't include an interface with a library package. I feel
   like this depends mostly on the size of the library/interface as
   to whether it makes sense.

I haven't seen very many packages that include a `__main__.py`, if any, so I'm not sure if people just don't use them or I haven't been using the right packages. The fact that I couldn't find any blog posts or articles dealing with `__main__.py` and distutils suggests to me that it's not a particularly popular combination, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer with some googling that resulted in me finding [this article about using _*main*_.py](http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2010/03/various-ways-of-distributing-python.html), I think I'm probably going to go with a layout along the lines of:

```
foo/
    foo/
        __main__.py
        ...
    scripts/
        foo
```

where `scripts/foo` is just

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python foo "$@"
```

This seems like it will install cleanly, *and* let people use my module without installing, just by doing `python path/to/foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Calling a module `__main__.py` is a bad idea, since that name has a special meaning. Instead use a [main sentinel](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) in `__init__.py` and create a script that does `exec python -m foo`.

Comment: my understanding of this is that if my foo/__init__.py has `if __name__ == "__main__":\n print 'success.'`, and I do `python -m foo`, I should see "success." Instead I get: "foo is a package and cannot be directly executed". Same thing happens if I stick the command in a script.

Comment: Also, I thought I was relying on the special characteristics of `__main__.py`? Unless there are other ones, I thought all it did was to make a directory executable as a script.

Comment: There are no special characteristics for `__main__.py`. It's just another (valid, yet strange) module name.

Comment: ah. It's `exec python -m foo/__init__`. Thanks! What is the etiquette for requesting a correction in an answer to accept it?

Comment: Oh, you're actually wrong about `__main__.py`. If you have `foo/__main__.py` and you do `python foo` it will run the code in `__main__`. Or at least it does for me.

Comment: I see, it's new with Python 3. The problem is that Python 3 still doesn't have a lot of popularity.

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.2/using/cmdline.html (down below the <script> section) it was changed in 2.5. So, you know, a new thing for you to use?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Python 3 changed it so that it *also* works with `-m`.